# Not able to spit the otp properly suggested by keyboard in iphone

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, safari

HTML:

```
<div class="otp-widget" validate>
        <input type="text" maxlength="1" name="otp-1" id="otpDigit1" autocomplete="no" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" oninput="handlePaste(this)" />
        <input type="text" maxlength="1" name="otp-2" id="otpDigit2" autocomplete="no" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" />
        <input type="text" maxlength="1" name="otp-3" id="otpDigit3" autocomplete="no" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" />
        <input type="text" maxlength="1" name="otp-4" id="otpDigit4" autocomplete="no" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" oninput="verifyOTPUponInput(this)" />
      </div>
```

JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.otp-widget input').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (el.getAttribute('id') == 'otpDigit1') {
      document.querySelector('.otp-widget-error').innerHTML = '';
      document.querySelector('.otp-widget-error').classList.add('d-none');
    };
    var { maxLength, value, name } = e.target;
    var [fieldName, fieldIndex] = name.split("-");

    if (e.keyCode === 8|| e.keyCode === 46) {
      var { value, maxLength, name } = e.target;
      var [fieldName, fieldIndex] = name.split("-");

      var prevSibling = document.querySelector(
        `input[name=otp-${parseInt(fieldIndex, 10) - 1}]`
      );

      if (value.length < maxLength) {
        if (prevSibling !== null) {
          prevSibling.focus();
        }
      }
    }else if(!isNaN(value)){
      // Check if they hit the max character length
      if (value.length == maxLength) {
        // Check if it's not the last input field
        if (parseInt(fieldIndex, 10) < 4) {
          // Get the next input field
          var nextSibling = document.querySelector(
            `input[name=otp-${parseInt(fieldIndex, 10) + 1}]`
          );

          // If found, focus the next field
          if (nextSibling !== null) {
            el.blur();
            nextSibling.focus();
            nextSibling.select();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  el.addEventListener('paste', (e) => {
    var paste = (e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text');
    if (paste) {
      if (!isNaN(parseInt(paste))) {
        paste = paste.split('');
        var inputCount = document.querySelectorAll('.otp-widget input').length;
        var loopLen = inputCount;
        if (paste.length < inputCount) {
          loopLen = paste.length;
        };
        for (let i = 0; i < loopLen; i++) {
          document.querySelector(`input[name=otp-${i+1}]`).value = paste[i];
        };
        document.querySelector(`input[name=otp-${loopLen}]`).focus();
        verifyOTPUponInput();
      } else {
        document.querySelectorAll('.otp-widget input').forEach(input => {
          input.value = '';
        });
      };
    };
  });
});

function handlePaste(el) {
  const paste = el.value;
  const inputCount = document.querySelectorAll('.otp-widget input').length;
  const loopLen = Math.min(paste.length, inputCount);

  // Clear all inputs first
  document.querySelectorAll('.otp-widget input').forEach((input) => {
    input.value = '';
  });

  // Set the input values from the paste
  for (let i = 0; i < loopLen; i++) {
    document.querySelector(`input[name=otp-${i + 1}]`).value = paste[i];
  }

  // If not all fields are filled, focus on the next field
  if (loopLen < inputCount) {
    document.querySelector(`input[name=otp-${loopLen + 1}]`).focus();
  }

  // Call verification function
  verifyOTPUponInput();
}
```

This code seems to be working fine everywhere very smoothly. OTP splitting, OTP pasting and all the functions in all browsers except safari browser in iphones.

In iphones keyboard suggests the otp which we get in messages and when I click on that suggestion. The otp gets filled as below screenshot:
[image]

How to resolve this issue once and for all ?